# Fine-tune refreshing of multiple models in Ember route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

There's a well known approach to support loading more than one model promise in an Ember route, using `Ember.RSVP.hash`:

```
// app/routes/posts.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      posts: this.store.findAll('post', params),
      tags: this.store.findAll('tag', params),
    });
  },

});
```

Now I have a `page` param, to be able to load the posts in batches, instead of loading them and showing them all at once.  But page changes do not alter the tags. However, when the page param changes, the whole model of the route is triggered again to re-load, causing the app to re-fetch both the posts for the new page, and the same tags all over again.

Is there a way to fine-tune this so that the tags are not loaded when certain params change?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to refacto your code. Like moving tags out of model. Or doing pagination differently (w/o model refresh). The one I like is writing a custom getAll utility.

```
var cache = {}; // model_name => Promise<[Record]>

function getAll(store, model) {
    if(!store.modelFor(model).cacheable) {
        return store.findAll(model);
    }

    if(!cache[model]) {
        cache[model] = store.findAll(model);
    }

    return cache[model];
}
```

And in your model now

```
import { getAll } from 'utils/store';
...
tags: getAll('tag'),
```

Comment: The thing is, in the actual scenario I'm facing (which is not the posts and tags example of course) one of the sub-models fetched in the `Ember.RSVP.hash` depends on some but not all of the route params having changed. The other depends on any param having changed. So I still need the model hook `params` to fetch the second sub-model. I just don't want it to be re-fetched when the param that changed does not affect its result.

Comment: Well you could modify given example above according to your needs add additional argument to cache properties (params) If param is the same and model name is the same then take from cache otherwise load new.

Comment: @Ernesto any success ?

Comment: I ended up not using any caching solution, you know because of that mantra that says there are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things. I ended up extracting the second sub-model that does not always change, and took it into a component that is the only place in the page where this additional model is used. The component is notified when the relevant parameters change and refreshes the data.